# I want to search by under specific condition in states

Tags: corda

I created user state, I want to search user state by userName,

This code is current search code,

```
val userName = "Bob"
val userstates = proxy.vaultQueryBy<UserState>().states
val results = userstates.filter { it.state.data.userName == userName }
```

But If the number of users exceeds 201, an error occurs,

In case of linear ID search, I used this code,

```
val criteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(linearId = listOf(UniqueIdentifier.fromString(userId)), status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
val userstates = proxy.vaultQueryBy<UserState>(criteria=criteria).states
```

Is it possible to obtain a userName by using criteria? Thank you for reading,

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a bit lame, but have you considered paging the result set in batches of 200?

See the `paging: PageSpecification` in https://docs.corda.net/api-vault-query.html